# Unrecognized Field in Dropwizard config.yml File while connecting aerospike

Tags: caching, dropwizard, aerospike

My config.yml file

logging: 
-level: INFO
-loggers:
--io.dropwizard.archetypes: DEBUG
mongo:
-host: localhost
-port: 27017
-database: User
aerospike:
-host: localhost
-port: 3000

I am getting the following error while launching the application.

io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException: config.yml has an error:

- Unrecognized field at: aerospike
  Did you mean?:

  - server
  - logging
  - metrics
  - admin
  - mongo
    [1 more]

I am using mongodb database and for cache I want to use aerospike. But I am getting error when adding aerospike in config.yml file